# ThinkPad X1 Extreme Battery discharging issues

Tags: battery, thinkpad, powercfg

I have a ThinkPad X1 Extreme running Win 11. These ThinkPads don't have a good reputation for battery life, but the battery seems to discharge very quickly while in sleep or hibernation. Today I closed the lid of my laptop for maybe half an hour and when I opened it up again it was out of battery, having drained 33% in that time.

This is the battery usage graph which says my battery was at 33% at 11:00, though the battery icon on the taskbar shows it's empty as of 11:57:
[image]

What makes the problem even more frustrating is I often don't get the Low Battery warning before the system shuts down, it just goes blank.

I've tried different combinations of settings, including:

- Set to balance performance and energy consumption in Control Panel
- Turn off fast start-up in Control Panel
- turn on all energy efficiency recommendations in power settings
- perform battery guage reset through Lenovo Vantage (this apparently improved my esitmated battery life "From 55.18 Wh to 56.45 Wh")
- `powercfg /batteryreport` says battery capacity is 61,900 mWh of 80,400 mWh
- I've just replaced my CMOS battery, which was dead

These are the full details of the Celxpert li-polymer battery:
[image]

I've had the laptop for four years, so I'm prepared to buy a new battery, but I just don't want to get a new battery and find that it's a software issue and the problem persists. I normally live on the road, in Australia, and charge my laptop off a auxiliary car battery, so I can't just leave my laptop plugged in overnight.